# Why I am getting 405 method not allowed error in Laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel

Calling ajax function but getting this error-

> home/asif/fanslive/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteCollection.php.
>
> Request Method: POST
>
> Status Code: 405 Method Not Allowed
>
> Remote Address: 192.168.0.4:80
>
> Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

Here is the code-

```
window.ajaxCall = function (url, data, method, dataType, successHandlerFunction, processDataFlag, contentTypeFlag) {
if(typeof(processDataFlag) == 'undefined'){
  processDataFlag = true;
}
if(typeof(contentTypeFlag) == 'undefined'){
  contentTypeFlag = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
}
$(".js-data-table .overlay").show();
geturl = $.ajax({
    url: url,
    data: data,
    processData: processDataFlag,
    contentType: contentTypeFlag,
    type: method,
    dataType: dataType,
    cache: false,
    success: successHandlerFunction,
    headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') },
    complete: function() {
        $(".js-data-table .overlay").hide();
    }
});
}

var data = "latitude=54&longitude=21&id=1"';
ajaxCall("getGenralSettingData", data, 'POST', 'json','');
Route::group(['prefix' => '{club}',  'middleware' => ['check.cms.panel']], function()
{
    Route::post('/getGenralSettingData', 'SampleController@getGenralSettingData')->name('backend.sample.data');
});
```

Comment: What is the page you are using this url on? You are calling the url without an `/` in front so the url is called relatively to the current page.

Comment: `console.log(url)` . The `methodNotAllowed` exception indicates that a route doesn't exist for the HTTP method you are requesting.

Comment: @Jerodev  thanks  i put ../ its working fine.